# Is "yo soy" implicit when refering to times?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I was listening to Afrosound's "Sabor Navideño" and the first thing they say is "Ay, qué soledad en esta Navidad". Is the "yo soy", that is to say, the sentence would otherwise have been "Ay, que soledad yo soy de esta Navidad", implicit?

Source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yndkCzqaAg

Comment: The phrase "qué soledad yo soy de esta Navidad" (note the diacritic accent on *qu**é***) makes no sense. Maybe you're trying to say "qué solo estoy [en] esta Navidad" ("how alone I am this Christmas")? That's not what the song is saying, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lyrics do not always follow grammatical rules. I don't think "qué soledad de esta Navidad" is a correct sentence in everyday Spanish.

The correct sentence would have been:

> (1) Qué soledad esta Navidad.

OR

> (2) Qué soledad **la** de esta Navidad.

In (1), as @aparente001 said "(yo) siento" could be the elided subject and verb. Another possible verb could be the impersonal "hay" (there is), in which case "qué soledad" would be the direct object and "esta Navidad", an adverbial of time.

In (2), the subject would be "la (soledad) de esta Navidad" and "qué soledad", the subject complement. Copulative "es" has been elided. "qué" substitutes for some unspecified intensifier, like "mucha", "tanta", "demasiada", etc. The author of the song must have found that there was not enough space for "la" and left it out, and thus produced an incorrect sentence.

Outside of an exclamatory situation, the normal sentence would be:

> - La de esta Navidad es mucha/tanta/demasiada soledad.

In an exclamatory context, subject and subject complement are swapped:

> - Qué (mucha/tanta/demasiada) soledad (es) la de esta Navidad.

Comment: As you suggested in your opening, Gustavson, lyrics can be a bit sloppy. They have to evoke a feeling and they have to fit with the music. // I like your "hay" idea. // Wasn't there a Billie Holliday song that was released around Christmas, that had to have an emergency recall to get it off the jukeboxes after one day, because the suicide rate spiked?  Christmas can be a sad time -- partly because of unrealistic expectations. // Did you listen to it?  At least the version I heard was mostly instrumental, and then when the vocal line started, it was very much in the background.  Subtle.

Comment: So, I don't think we need to demand perfect syntax of this song.

Answer (score 1):

I listened to the [tune on youtube](https://youtu.be/sgKp-NEtPrQ) and I read the [lyrics](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/9879220/Various+Artists/Sabor+Navide%C3%B1o+Afrosound).  I think what you are asking is this: The first line, *Ay, qué soledad de esta Navidad*, is a sentence fragment; what is the implicit subject and verb here?  Is it "yo soy"?

No.  If we were to write down a complete sentence that this fragment might have come from, it would likely be

> Ay, qué soledad **siento [yo]** de esta Navidad.

Notice that another line in the song is also a fragment, *Tomando ron na' más*.  A complete sentence that this could be taken from would be

> **[Yo] estoy** tomando ron na' más.